# spark error: in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, rdd

i'm using spark-shell to run spark hbase script.
When i run this command :

```
val job = Job.getInstance(conf)
```

I got this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
```

The error is due to running in `spark-shell`. Please use `spark-submit`, this should solve your problem.

Comment: there is no way to do it with spark-shell